# Image file order Number

Tags: c#-3.0

How to find the file order number from the folder. My image files are stored in IMAGE folder by ascending oder.

For example,

imgA
imgB
imgC
imgD

i want to know

imgA is 1, imgB is 2 imgC 3

How to get the ascending order numbers as per filename.?

Comment: Actually, not true. In general, folders store sets of file and order is just random. But when reading the folder content, the OS will often present the data to you in a predetermined order. All you've done is give ascending filenames to your files.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `DirectoryInfo` to get all the file name, and then obtain the file index

```
    public static int SortFileNames(string yourDirectory, string selectedFile)
    {
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(yourDirectory);
    FileInfo[] files =directory.GetFiles();
    return  GetFileIndex(files, selectedFile);
    }

   private  static int GetFileIndex(FileInfo[] files, string selectedFile)
  {
     for(int i=0; i< files.length; i++)
     {
        if(files[i].Name== selectedFile)
          return i;
     }
    return -1;
  }
```

Comment: My file not only start from img*. i will be different.
If different means, how can i fine the order number of fileNames in the folder.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you say.

Comment: How to find the file order number from the folder. My image files are stored in IMAGE folder by ascending oder.

For example,

imgA imgB imgC imgD

i want to know 

imgA is 1, imgB is 2 imgC 3

How to get the ascending order numbers as per filename.?

Answer (score 0):

That should work :

```
var imagesIndexes = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.jpg")
                    .Select(fullPath => Path.GetFileName(fullPath)
                    .OrderBy(fileName => fileName)
                    .Select((fileName, index) => new {FileName = fileName, Index = index})
                    .ToDictionary(item => item.FileName, item => item.Index);


int indexOfFoo = imagesIndexes["Foo.jpg"];
int indexOfBar = imagesIndexes["Bar.jpg"];
```

Or, a bit simpler :

```
var images = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.jpg")
             .Select(fullPath => Path.GetFileName(fullPath)
             .OrderBy(fileName => fileName);


int indexOfFoo = images.IndexOf("Foo.jpg");
int indexOfBar = images.IndexOf("Bar.jpg");
```